# I2C slave not pulling down SDA data line for the full clock cycle

Tags: i2c, clock

I am communicating with some slave devices via multiple busses, however even though they are all the same device (http://www.invensense.com/mems/gyro/mpu3050.html) and all receive the same message/clock from the master, they don't hold the SDA line down for the same amount of time:

[image: Devices]

If you notice, devices 1 and 3 do not pull down for the same length of time as devices 2 and 4.  However they are all the same type of device receiving the same messages from the master.

In this instance, devices 1 and 3 are causing problems because their changing from low to high (due to not holding the line low for long enough time) on the same clock cycle which should not happen during slave ACK or slave data sending:

[image: Issues]

The device I am using to send and capture these signals (simultaneously) is a National Instruments PXI device that oversamples at 1 MHz which should be plenty so I don't think its simply a display issue.

I thought it could be a timing issue of some sort, but per the [MPU-3050 device specifications](http://www.invensense.com/mems/gyro/documents/PS-MPU-3000A.pdf) on page 16, it adhears to I2C FAST-MODE:

[image: timing]

My current timing parameters are much slower than that so they should be valid inputs:

```
tSU;STA - 4700 ns
tHD;STA - 4000 ns
tSU;DAT - 1000 ns
tHD;DAT - 4000 ns
tSU;STO - 4000 ns
tBUF - 4700 ns
tHIGH - 4000 ns
fSCL - 80 kHz
```

My only real requirement is I need the device to ALSO satisfy the STANDARD-MODE specifications for I2C (as my above ones do) because I plan to add more devices to these busses that won't allow FAST-MODE.

I really have no idea of what could be happening here, so its possible its not even a timing issue at all.  I've tried some "trial-error" stuff with the timing, but similar behavior always occurs.  If you have any ideas as to how I could try to fix this, please let me know!

Comment: I think we need to see real oscilloscope traces. There are two many subtle problems that a logic analyzer will miss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variation in delay you're seeing is immaterial. I<sup>2</sup>C is a *synchronous* protocol, so the only thing that matters is whether or not the SDA line is still low on the next rising edge of SCL. As you can see in your first diagram, they all pull SDA low before that happens, so they are behaving correctly.

If this is causing problems on your I<sup>2</sup>C master, then it is implemented incorrectly.

In fact, the rising edges you've circled are caused when the master *stops* driving the SDA low itself, and have nothing to do with the slave devices' activity. They haven't yet driven the line at all.

(The timing variation you see is probably due to the asynchronous nature of your logic analyzer's sampling.)

Comment: So you are saying I should simply acquire data on each rising edge of the clock and ignore the falling edge overlap since its not an issue?  (Sorry if that's a silly question, I'm pretty new to serial protocols.  I recall reading that the data needs to be consistent across the entire clock in the specifications so what I have implemented in the master is probably wrong.)

Comment: It could also be a difference in the pull-up resistors on the SDA line. You don't see that on a logic analyzer.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma: Yes, that's correct. In fact, if you have a mix of different-speed devices, you may need to allow for "clock stretching" in your master. Clock stretching is when a slave holds the SCL line low until it is ready to act on the current data bit. In your master, you need to stop driving the SCL line low, then poll it until it actually goes high, and *then* sample the SDA line.

Comment: "the only thing that matters is whether or not the SDA line is still low on the next rising edge of SCL" Are you sure? It seems to me I2C is designed to be possibly implemented with latches as the sampling element rather than flip-flops, and SDA switching prematurely (before the SCL falling edge) could result in latching in the wrong data.

Comment: @ThePhoton You are correct, sir. From the NXP I2C spec: "The data on the SDA line must be stable during the HIGH period of the clock. The HIGH or LOW state of the data line can only change when the clock signal on the SCL line is LOW" Transitions on SDA when the clock is high are used as the special START and STOP conditions.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Yes, I'm sure. If latches are used, the overall effect must still be (from the point of view of the bus) as though they're edge-triggered. Note that if SDA changes while SCL is high (i.e., prior to a falling edge), it constitutes a special "start" or "stop" condition in the I2C protocol.

Comment: So, it *does* matter if SDA changes before SCL goes low?

Comment: Dave's solution seems to have solved my issue though.  I notice no data inconsistencies on rising edges, and the data I'm reading back from the slaves seems consistent with what I should expect.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Yes, that's what I said. But in that case, it means something other than the transfer of a data bit. Data bits are only transferred on rising edges of SCL. I really don't know what point you're trying to make -- please state it more plainly.

Comment: @ThePhoton: If the time between an SCL falling edge and the next change to SDA is sufficiently short that some devices think SDA fell first, that is apt to cause severe problems, especially if SDA was a rising edge.  If the next seven bits clocked out match the address of the device that misinterpreted the SDA edge as preceding the SCL edge, that device may assert its own SDA line at inappropriate times; in some scenarios, it could cause a total I2C bus lock-up (normally no slave is allowed to assert SDA for more than eight consecutive clock cycles, but...

Comment: @ThePhoton: Two slave devices that were both erroneously activated simultaneously could together hold the SDA wire permanently low--a state which the master would be powerless to resolve.

Comment: @Dave, You said "the only thing that matters is whether or not the SDA line is still low on the next rising edge of SCL". My point is that it's also important to keep SDA constant as long as SCL stays high. That's another thing other than the thing you said was the only thing. OP's measurements don't have enough time resolution to show whether or not he is violating this rule or not.

Comment: @ThePhoton: All right, I didn't spell it out explicitly enough: The only thing that matters *after SCL goes low* is whether or not SDA is still low on the next rising edge of SCL. What you're talking about is a basic violation of the I2C specification.

Answer (score 1):

Many processor-based I2C slave devices leave the question of whether to acknowledge an incoming byte up to software, which will often make that decision after the falling clock edge which would mark the start of the time the slave device may generate the acknowledge.  A slave device which immediately knows whether or not a byte should be acknowledged by generate the acknowledgement immediately, without using clock stretching, but if a device doesn't know immediately whether to acknowledge a byte can buy itself time to make that determination by holding SCL low until it has either started driving the acknowledge signal or decided that it's not going to.